# Cannot find name 'fetch'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am able use fetch api newly created reactjs app.
But I am using [this](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) template and it says cant find fetch api.
[image]

whats wrong here? I encounter smilar issues how can I fix it?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you are using Typescript 2.8.0+ fetch is included in the standard lib.

You will need to use "--lib dom" or add "dom" in your *tsconfig.json*:

1. old ❌

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom"],
  }
}
```

2. new ✅

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM"],
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. Can I catch the eye of a moderator with this comment?

Comment: It's should be `"lib": ["DOM"],` for now. ✅

Comment: don't work for me in jest + vite + TS.

Comment: also doesn't work for nx + nestjs

Answer (score 14):

You most likely will need the typescript typings for fetch, just try

`npm install --save-dev @types/whatwg-fetch`

should sort out the error your getting.

Comment: @types/whatwg-fetch has been deprecated apparently.

Comment: Just need to set your tsconfig to include "DOM" in the "lib" array, in addition to whatever you have already